# Datepicker values not send to email in php

Tags: php, html, email, datepicker

I created one sample form. After submit the form all values are send to my email but selected Datepicker values not send to email.

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="date-picker" name="arrival" id="datepicker">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>    
        <input class="date-picker" name="departure" id="datepicker1"/>
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name *" name="fname" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name *" required name="lname">
                                                </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
              $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
         $departure = $_POST['departure'];
        $secretinfo = $_POST['info'];

            
         
            if ($secretinfo == "")
            {
               $myemail = "rajkumar23@gmail.com";
        $emess.= "Arrival: ".$arrival. "\n";
           $emess.= "Departure: ".$departure. "\n";
        $emess.= "First Name: ".$fname."\n";
               $emess.= "Last Name: ".$lname."\n";
        $ehead = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
               $subj = "Booking Enquiry from ".$fname." ".$lname."!";
               $mailsend=mail("$myemail","$subj","$emess","$ehead");
               if($mailsend){
        echo "success";
        }
        } 
        }
        ?>
          ?>
```

How to send the datepicker values into email.

Comment: remove extra space `name="arrival "`, didnt find `submit` button in your code

Comment: did u checked the solution.

Comment: yes i checked firstname and last ame values are send to email but datepicker values are not send to email

Comment: check the answer given below

Comment: ok i removed but the mail still not sending is there any issue for send mail

Comment: well now this is configuration issue on you local

Comment: `$mailsend=mail("$myemail","$subj","$emess","$ehead");` should be `$mailsend=mail($myemail,$subj,$emess,$ehead);`

Comment: answer updated, check it.

Comment: I update the code but it is also not working. i received first name and last name in email but datepicker value not shows in email

Comment: Share the result of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: selected datepicker prints within the page but not to send email ex: prints 20-05-2014

Comment: print_r($_POST); chk the result

Comment: It prints the selected value within the page. but not send to email.

Comment: Share the result plz . result of array

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove extra space from `arrival` field:

```
<input class="date-picker" name="arrival " id="datepicker" required>
```

*Use like that:*

```
<input class="date-picker" name="arrival" id="datepicker" required>
```

*`name="arrival "` this will return you Undefined Index error.*

One more thing, always use php [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in your development mode not for production mode.

*I didn't find the `submit` button in your code, i hope you are using in your application.*

---

**Update 1:**

You need to remove quote from `mail()`

```
$mailsend=mail("$myemail","$subj","$emess","$ehead");
```

**Should be:**

```
$mailsend=mail($myemail,$subj,$emess,$ehead);
```